# How to use cadquery server ui import?

Tags: importerror, cadquery

I would like to experiment a bit with cadquery, it looks pretty cool!
So, I installed the package using pip following the documentation (see https://cadquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). So far so good.

Next, I tried cadquery-server to render models (https://pypi.org/project/cadquery-server/).
Installation is fine, server is up and running and accessible on default address.

Now, in the python script describing an example model, one should import the ui, by adding `from cq_server.ui import ui, show_object` at the begining of the script.
Here I get into trouble, my IDE (VS code) complains that import "cq_server.ui" could not be resolved.
Subsequently, the model is not rendered.
I must be missing something obvious here... Any thoughts?

```
 import cadquery as cq
 from cq_server.ui import ui, show_object

 # These can be modified rather than hardcoding values for each dimension.
 length = 80.0  # Length of the block
 height = 60.0  # Height of the block
 thickness = 10.0  # Thickness of the block

 # Create a 3D block based on the dimension variables above.
 result = cq.Workplane("XY").box(length, height, thickness)

 # Displays the result of this script
 show_object(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same problem. I could not get any help. However I found a solution that is even more pleasing. Try to use build123d together with vscode-ocp-cad-viewer, both available on GitHub.
Read "readthedocs" of build123, go to the section "External Tools and Libraries", and there follow the instructions "see: ocp-vscode".

Comment: Thank you very much! Using the github projects you referred to I was able run some examples and render using the VScode plugin. This should be a sufficient starting point to get experimenting. Thanks again for sharing.